# postgresql function execution taking too long

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my Postgres funtion

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_me(test_id _int4)
  RETURNS TEXT
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  tempIds INT[];
  returnValue TEXT := 'Success';
BEGIN

  RAISE NOTICE ' selecting  abc_id for  : %', test_id;

  tempIds := ARRAY ( SELECT DISTINCT abc_id
                     FROM test
                     WHERE test_id IN ( SELECT unnest(test_id)) );

  RAISE NOTICE ' selected abc_id are : %', tempIds;

  RETURN returnValue;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

and I am executing it like this

```
select test_me('{123}'::int[]);
```

It takes forever to run and I observed that only the first notice is printed during the execution and it never reaches to the second notice statement. when I run the select query inside `ARRAY` method it executes quickly.

Edit 1: When I tried running the select query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT abc_id 
FROM test
WHERE test_id IN (123)
```

it executed very fast as test_id is an indexed column.

But when I tried it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT abc_id 
FROM test
WHERE test_id IN ( SELECT unnest('{123}'::int[])
```

It took lot of time since due to unnest inside IN clause query was using a sequential scan on test_id column and taking a lot of time to run.

So the main culprit is the `unnest` inside `IN` clause.

Any substitute to use an array inside an in clause with indexed search?

Comment: Did you run `EXPLAIN` on that query?

Comment: How long does the query take when you run it manually outside of the function. What is the execution plan of the query? How many rows does the query aggregate (i.e. how many elements will the final array contain)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it takes around 20 ms.

Comment: `_int4` is a custom type? is it array? what is `ARRAY` method?

Comment: @VaoTsun in postgresql its shorthand for int[]

Comment: @sumit cool - thank you. and the `ARRAY method`?

Comment: @unkmas can you please check question again. I have updated it !

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please check now !

Comment: No need for `unnest`. Try: `test_id = ANY ( test_id )`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks 
 it worked ! its using indexed search with any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) instead of `unnest` inside `IN` clause using

`test_id = ANY( test_id )`

fixed the issue !

Comment: Accept this answer :)